# total size of all files smaller than

Tags: linux, bash

So I'm planning a backup, there's thousands of files in the subdirectories and I know that the largest ones are just datasets that I don't need to backup, as opposed to stuff I created.

I found this useful command [here](https://superuser.com/questions/233616/list-files-bigger-than-filesize-specified#233619) which lists everything bigger than or smaller than a given size:

If I do:

```
find . -type f -size +1000M
```

it lists only 4 files, but for +100M there's about 30 of them. I can look through and see if there's anything important in there that needs to stay and adjust the threshold accordingly.

Would like a total size so I know if it will all fit on an optical disk of 25 or 100MB..

So I tried to pipe it into `du` like this but it doesn't seem to work, ie give me a total number of say the 4 files found:

```
find . -type f -size +1000M | du
```

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

(Yes, of course will change the + to a - , less than not greater than before looking at the number but it's easier to see if it is working while looking at 30 rather than thousands of file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run `find` with `-printf`, which has a lot of options to control what it prints (documented [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html)). So you can print each file, followed by how many 1 kilobyte disk blocks it uses, with:

```
find . -type f -size +1000M -printf '%p %k\n'
```

Once you've done that, it's easier to sum them with `awk` than with `du`:

```
find . -type f -size +1000M -printf '%p %k\n'  | awk 'BEGIN{total=0}{total += $2}END{print total}'
```

That's because `du` only accepts an input list if it's terminated by `NUL` (ASCII 0). So you'd have to do:

```
find . -type f -size +1000M -printf '%p\0' | du -k --files0-from=- --total
```

and then look at the last, "total", line. But the `NUL`-terminated list of filenames is not user-friendly to look at; without usernames, the filenames look run together.

Comment: Thanks, your middle command produces a very elegant output. Thankfully your examples and @Kent 's are all producing the same number, but although that is a nasty looking command you wrote its output is totally clean. Don't know where you guys learn this bash stuff I need it now and then, might have to look into it..

Answer (score 1):

```
 du --total $(find . -type f -size +1000M)
```

will help you.

Answer (score 1):

In order to find out, if some files will fit on another media, you have to take into account the block size of the other media. It is not sufficient to summarize just the bytes of each file, because each file wastes disk space in the last block. The amount of wasted space depends on the block size.

Example from my home directory on my virtual machine:

```
$ du -hs .
619M    .
$ du -bhs .
598M    .
```

The files are 598M big, but they use 619M on disk. About 20M is wasted.

Comment: Thanks yes have noticed that. It's probably okay for the blueray disk to say deduct 5% from the size of the media and not exceed that. Interesting to see there is a command line tool like this..